# Cleaning a text: R vs Python

Tags: r, data-preprocessing

I have a "dirty" text with statements as

> L'intervento ÃẀ mirato all'eliminazione nonchÃ© alla...

where I have **ÃẀ** instead of **è**, **Ã©** instead of **é**, etc.
Which is the best language for manipulating the text automatically? R or Python? And what about the others?

ps= the text I'm trying to "adjust" has already been read wrongly (with the wrong encoding). For this reason I have ÃẀ instead of è, etc.

Comment: What does "cleaning" this text mean to you?

Comment: Requests for R packages are off-topic here: have a look at our [help/on-topic] for more information. However, it is possible that your underlying issues about cleaning the data are on-topic here, so you might want to edit your question.

Comment: "Which language is the best for a task" generally falls under the same purview as "which package is the best"  - if the emphasis is on the software choice it's likely off-topic here. The essential issue here seems to be encoding though, which is essentially language-neutral: it's a basic task that could be solved in any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you give as an example is an issue of *encoding*.
You can tell most read.XXX commands about the encoding with the so-named parameter.

In your case you could try encoding="UTF-8".
For additional information on character encoding, refer to google or wikipedia.